# Eclipse Mars Release 4.5.0 shows errors on JAX-RS code (@Path contains regular expressions)

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jax-rs

I am currently coding a Restful Web Service using Eclipse Mars (Release 4.5.0 - Build ID: 20150621-1200).

Problem I am facing are code errors Eclipse identifies. The code is Mavenized and using Maven to compile and build the project results with **no** errors.

How do I make sure that Eclipse Mars identifies that my JAX-RS optional parameters, using regular expressions, are valid and not an issue?

Example:

[image]

The error Eclipse specifies (the red underlined `@Path` annotation value):

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The @Path annotation value '/list{lang:(/[a-z]{2})?}' is invalid: missing '{' or '}'.
    - The @Path template parameter '2' is not bound to any field, property or method parameter annotated with 
     @PathParam("2").
```

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you change `[a-z]{2}`  to `[a-z][a-z]`?

Comment: I did have it earlier and the error lines disappeared.

Comment: .. and you don't want to use this? Or is your question more "how to fix eclipse"?

Comment: I am using it but I find it as an issue as it works either way. It's all about preference. If JAX-RS works by using `[a-z]{2}` regular expression, Eclipse should not have to find the regular expression as an error. So, yes. How would 1 fix Eclipse with regards to this issue?